# creating a dynamic dictionary that pulls from a list and sub-lists

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and am working on a small project, part of my solution involves extracting data from a list by creating sub-lists and then updating a dictionary with a dynamic key that I can pull from later. But I keep running into an issue where the same date is being put into the dictionary 4 times then continuing in the loop for each set.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
    prb = dict()

    def arithmetic_arranger(problems):
        for problem in problems:
            for i in range(len(problems)):
                key=str("prb_"+str(i+1))
                prb[key]=problem.split()
            print(prb)

    arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

and this is the output:

```
    {'prb_1': ('32', '+', '698'), 'prb_2': ('32', '+', '698'), 'prb_3': ('32', '+', '698'), 'prb_4': ('32', '+', '698')}
    {'prb_1': ('3801', '-', '2'), 'prb_2': ('3801', '-', '2'), 'prb_3': ('3801', '-', '2'), 'prb_4': ('3801', '-', '2')}
    {'prb_1': ('45', '+', '43'), 'prb_2': ('45', '+', '43'), 'prb_3': ('45', '+', '43'), 'prb_4': ('45', '+', '43')}
    {'prb_1': ('123', '+', '49'), 'prb_2': ('123', '+', '49'), 'prb_3': ('123', '+', '49'), 'prb_4': ('123', '+', '49')}
```

But the desired output is:

```
    {'prb_1': ('32', '+', '698'), 'prb_2': ('3801', '-', '2'), 'prb_3': ('45', '+', '43'), 'prb_4': ('123', '+', '49')}
```

*Updated to reflect code as text and desired output

Comment: Post code as a text, not as an image. You should also provide the expected and actual output.

Comment: In the internal loop, change `problems` to `opperands`, and then inside that loop, change `opperands` to `opperands[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing you should consider about the data structures, mutability.
python list is mutable, so if you give it a name then modify it, It will be modified everywhere.
You can use immutable data structures here, like tuples.

you can change line 5 to:

```
operands = tuple(problem.split())
```

or you can change your code like this:

```
for problem in problems:
    for i in range(len(problems)):
        key=str("prb_"+str(i+1))
        prb[key] = problem.split()
```

Comment: Thank you, I plugged in the updated code and the dict still is changed on each pass with each item repeated throughout, and the final output is always

        {'prb_1': ('123', '+', '49'), 'prb_2': ('123', '+', '49'), 'prb_3': ('123', '+', '49'), 'prb_4': ('123', '+', '49')}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out

```
    prb = dict()

    def arithmetic_arranger(problems):
        for i in range(len(problems)):
            key=("prb_"+str(i+1))
            for problem in problems:
                problem = problems[i]
                value = problem.split()
            prb.update({key:value})
        print(prb)
        

    arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

with the following output:

```
    {'prb_1': ['32', '+', '698'], 'prb_2': ['3801', '-', '2'], 'prb_3': ['45', '+', '43'], 'prb_4': ['123', '+', '49']}
```

If any of you have an idea on how to simplify this please advise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).